# Django: SELECT JsonField AS new_name?

Tags: python, django

I have a table, in which some attributes are columns, and some are implemented as a postgres JsonField.

For the columns, I can write eg

```
Product.objects.values(brand=F('brand_name'))
```

for implement a `SELECT brand_name AS brand` query.

I need to do something similar for a JsonField, eg

```
Product.objects.values(color=F('jsonproperties__color'))
```

However, the `F` expressions [do not work correctly](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29769) with JsonFields, and there doesn't seem to be a fix coming anytime soon.

How could I work around this?

Comment: Is there one `color` property per Product object?

Comment: Yes, as key of the json

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple list comprehension will do what you want:

```
[{"color": p["jsonproperties"]["color"]} for p in Product.objects.values("color")]
```